# c# get access to variable inside method from another method

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a small Stopwatch, but I am stuck - how can I get access to the variable inside method from another method.

```
public class StopWatch
    {
        public TimeSpan Duration;

        public void Start()
        {
            var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public TimeSpan Stop()
        {
            var endTime = DateTime.Now - startTime
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't access variables from other functions, you need to make them class members.

Comment: Impossible: local variables are local... but you can to define some at the class level as field or property. Private or protected field, for example.

Answer (score 1):

you can use class variables

```
public class StopWatch
{
    public TimeSpan Duration;

    private DateTime _startTime ;
    private DateTime _endTime;

    public void Start()
    {
         _startTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public TimeSpan Stop()
    {
         _endTime = DateTime.Now - startTime
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of Duration?

Comment: how much time passed, it's supposed to be a read-only property